# How do I access phantomjs addCookie() method?

Tags: javascript, cookies, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I have a problem that I cannot find the addCookie() method which is needed to create a cookie in phantomJS.

In my *package.json* I have **phantomjs-prebuilt** installed, but cannot addCookie() method when I require phantomjs --> require('phantomjs');

How do I get access to the addCookie() and all other related methods.

Here is an example, but access to the file where this method is supposed to reside is nowhere to be found

http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/add-cookie.html

Version of phantomjs-prebuilt (the latest):

> "phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.16"

Comment: can it be your version? (from docs - Introduced: PhantomJS 1.7)

Comment: The version I have is the latest...2+